# Catch ContextErrorException from Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

I'm reading a XML file in PHP and want to do this within a `try catch` block so i can handle exceptions (broken files).

So my code for this looks like this:

```
try{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    //do stuff
}
```

But instead of the catch i'm getting this Exception message:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 4284: parser error : Premature end of data in tag Data line 2201
```

I'm not even sure if this is a real Exception because of the `Warning:` right after that, is it a warning and not a Exception? If it is a Exception, why can't i catch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself by changing the error handler:

```
set_error_handler(
    function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext)
    { 
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    }
);
```

I'm not sure, but i'm guessing that the Exception that i recieved was indeed a warning, so it couldn't be catched.